# Проблема с Maven

Tags: java, android, xml, maven

Пытаюсь использовать прогрессбар из [этого репозитория](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

Подключаю его с помощью Maven, но ничего не получается. Целиком копирую этот код в свой pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.lzyzsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>circleprogress</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

и получаю ошибку

```
Missing artifact com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:apklib:1.1.0
```

Как решить эту проблему? С Maven знаком слабо, прошу не ругать сильно.

Comment: Покажите содержимое pom.xml. 
Какая IDE используется? Можно через интерфейс среды выполнить данную операцию

Comment: @DeKaNszn  Eclipse

Comment: убери тэг type, чтобы было
<dependency> <groupId>com.github.lzyzsd</groupId> <artifactId>circleprogress</artifactId> <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: ни малейшего эффекта

Comment: Возможно, что Eclipse не обновил конфигурацию, @JuniorThree, пробовал переоткрывать проект? Либо попробовать нажать на правую кнопку на проекте, выбрать Maven => **Update Project Configuration**, поможет?

Comment: [maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.lzyzsd%7Ccircleprogress%7C1.1.0%7Caar) рапортует, что такой артефакт существует. На какой стадии выдается ошибка, выдает ли мавен какую-нибудь информацию о том, где он ищет и что получает? Пробовали прибить локальный кэш репозитория?

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что у вас указан следующий Maven-репозиторий:

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: извините за возможно глупый вопрос, а где его нужно указывать? У меня в pom.xml вообще нет секции repositiry. Или это где-то еще?

Comment: добавил в pom.xml но никакого эффекта. Та же ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Самостоятельно скачать из web репозитория и ручками положить/зарегистрировать в локальном депозитории.